# Dynamically add and remove class from the page angular 7

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, angular7, angular-httpclient

I am using angular 7 and I want to add and remove dynamically added class

I have api which is returning numbers.

What I want to do is highlight column box when there is number higher/lower

There is 2 different class on higher apply `.changeGreen` and on lower apply `.changeRed`

The problem is that when there is higher number and class is already applied then css is not affecting

i.e if `.changeGreen` is already applied and there is number is increased so `.changeGreen` class has to take affect and highlight box

COMPONENT FILE :

```
getCounter() {
        const endpoint1 = 'http://localhost:8080/counter';

        this.http.get<number>(endpoint1)
            .subscribe(data => {
                if (data) {
                    if (this.test1.subs < data) {
                        this.test1['subs'] = data
                        this.test1['class'] = 'changeGreen'
                    } else if (this.test1.subs > data) {
                        this.test1['subs'] = data
                        this.test1['class'] = 'changeRed'
                    } else {
                        this.test1['subs'] = data
                        this.test1['class'] = ''
                    }

                    console.log(this.test1);

                }
                setTimeout(() => { this.getCounter(); }, 2000);
            });
    }
```

HTML FILE :

```
    <div class="row" style="font-size: 25px;color: black;">
            <div class="col-md-3" [ngClass]="test1.class">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        01. <img src="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        Name <br>
                        <ng2-odometer [number]="test1.subs" [config]="{}"></ng2-odometer>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
            </div>
```

CSS FILE :

```
@keyframes fadeInOutGreen {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
    }

    45% {
        background-color: rgba(80, 240, 16, 0.7);
    }

    100% {
        background-color: white;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInOutRed {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
    }

    45% {
        background-color: rgba(240, 15, 15, 0.7);
    }

    100% {
        background-color: white;
    }
}

.changeGreen {  
    animation-name: fadeInOutGreen;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-duration: 1.2s;
}

.changeRed {  
    animation-name: fadeInOutRed;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly the issue is that when the class name `.changeGreen` already exists, and a new higher number is returned, class should be left the same but you want the effect of the class to be displayed?

If that is the case you could try empty the class in the beginning of each call and let it be applied from scratch depending on the number. Another way I can think of is checking if the class already exists an removing it before adding it again.

If you could provide a json returning from the endpoint maybe we could reproduce the issue.